# Find first and last visible row in specific range + border around range(first:last)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

I have a sheet, it has directions with numbers in Range(C31:C150)...
e.g. C31:C55 has N10, N11, N12,... C56:C75 has S40, 41, 42, etc.

Depending on if the neighbour cell in column D is empty, the helper column BA contains a 1 if filled or 0 if empty. I then hide all rows containing a 0 in the column BA.
Because this is a dynamic process it often messes up the borders around the directions ranges (C31:C55;C56:C75;etc.).

In my example, only C31 from the first range is visible.
In the 2nd range C56,57,60,63,64,65,72,73 are visible.

My goal is to get a border around C31 and C56:C73.
Actually its about getting a border around column C* to J*, but I hope to do that adjustment myself.

I tried these two approaches:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Range("C56:J75").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).BorderAround _
  ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium
```

This splits the range into multiple areas, as soon as a hidden row is found (C56:C57;C60;C63:C65;C72:C73).
Is there a way I can extract the row number of the upper and lower end? Like left(56), right(73) and then combine both?

Second approach:

```
Dim StartRow As Long, EndRow As Long
With Sheets("sheet1")
    StartRow = .Range("BA56:BA75").Find(what:=1, after:=.Range("BA56")).Row
    EndRow = .Range("BA56:BA75").Find(what:=1, after:=.Range("BA56"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End With
```

With the described example this gives me startrow 61 and endrow 71. Both hidden rows. The code worked properly for C31 (I guess it only works with grouped data).

While creating this question the automatic search found this:

```vb
Sub main()
    Dim firstCell As Range, lastCell As Range
    Set firstCell = first_non_blank_visible_cell(Range("$C$3:$C$5,$C$100:$C$64000"))
    Set lastCell = last_non_blank_visible_cell(Range("$C$3:$C$5,$C$100:$C$64000"))
    Debug.Print firstCell.Address
    Debug.Print lastCell.Address
End Sub

Function first_non_blank_visible_cell(rng As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    With rng.Areas(1)
        Set first_non_blank_visible_cell = .Cells(1)
    End With
End Function

Function last_non_blank_visible_cell(rng As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    With rng.Areas(rng.Areas.Count)
        Set last_non_blank_visible_cell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With
End Function
```

It worked, then I changed the range a second time for testing and it broke. Can't get it to work again, not even in the range it used to work.

Comment: A screenshot might be useful here.  Is there some way to identify all of the "blocks" within the table which would have originally been marked with a border around them?

Comment: Are you hiding the rows using autofilter, or some other method?

Comment: @TimWilliams I added a picture at the bottom of the post. there is a main sheet which actually contains the information for column BA. BA on the picture sheet is just a direct link to the main sheet. There is also information on the main sheet which identify the blocks, its basically all first letters of directions.

Comment: @TimWilliams I then use this code to hide the empty rows: `Sub hide_rowsBA()
    Dim cell As Range, unionRng As Range
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("BA1:BA1000")
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, cell)
            Else
                Set unionRng = cell
            End If End If Next
    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Comment: I was asking about hiding the rows because how you do that can affect the results from using `find()`, (depending on whether you use `Lookin:=xlValues` or `xlFormulas`) but that might not be relevant here.  Still need to know if you have a list of all of the ranges which (if all rows were visible) would have "border around", or some programmatic way to determine those ranges.  FYI `Find()` always remembers the setting you last-used (whether manually via the UI or using code), so ideally be sure to provide all the relevant arguments every time you call it.

Comment: okay, well on the main sheet i use if(S**<>0;1;0) in column BA. I guess i should add xlValues?! I dont have a programmatic way, but that wouldnt be too hard if needed. The Ranges are always the same, but every row within it could get hidden in the process: Range1: C31:J40 R2: C41:J55 R3: C55:J75 R4: C76:J95 R5: C96:J102 R6: C103:J114 R7: C115:J128

Comment: Be sure to run `ActiveSheet.Range("BA1:BA1000").EntireRow.Hidden = False` before hiding rows with zeros

Comment: i actually do run this before all the time:     `With ActiveSheet
    .Range("A:XFD").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    .Range("1:1000").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    .Range("BA:XFD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    .Range("1000:1048576").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End With` EDIT: damn, BA has to be visible, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit trickier than I'd thought but still possible:

```vb
Sub DoBordersAroundVisibleRows()
    Dim rF As Range, rL As Range, rw As Range, el
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'speed up
    ws.Range("C31:J128").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    
    'loop over each "block" in the range
    For Each el In Array("C31:J40", "C41:J55", "C55:J75", "C76:J95", _
                        "C96:J102", "C103:J114", "C115:J128")
        Set rF = Nothing 'reset first/last visible rows
        Set rL = Nothing
        For Each rw In ActiveSheet.Range(el).Rows 'loop rows in block
            If Not rw.EntireRow.Hidden Then       'row is visible?
                If rF Is Nothing Then             'first row gets a top border
                    Set rF = rw
                    ApplyBorders rF, xlEdgeTop
                End If
                Set rL = rw
                ApplyBorders rL, xlEdgeLeft, xlEdgeRight 'all rows get R/L borders
            End If
        Next rw
        If Not rF Is Nothing Then
            ApplyBorders rL, xlEdgeBottom 'last row gets bottom border
        End If
    Next el
End Sub

'Apply all borders supplied to `bordersToApply` to range `rng`
Sub ApplyBorders(rng As Range, ParamArray bordersToApply() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(bordersToApply)
        With rng.Borders(bordersToApply(i))
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is incredible. I am still a beginner, was searching for a solution for hours and you got the dedication to get it done in under 2 hours. You are a wizard. If i may ask, how did you start/learn with vba and how you keep up with new changes? I am trying to learn it mostly with wiseowl videos on yt - but often i am working on stuff that is way too specific to find a video about it. Writing this code here with an array seems lightyears aways from me. thank you so much

Comment: I starting using VBA in Excel 95, so almost 20 years ago now.  I learned it before YouTube was a thing, but even now I'd still prefer a good book.  This was my starting point: https://www.amazon.com/Excel-Windows-Power-Programming-VBA/dp/0764530011 (pretty much read it cover-to-cover) but of course there are more-recent versions...  The language itself has changed very little since then, but the Excel application has added a bunch of functionality along the way.